# Does anyone know what brick this is? Looks like half a cylinder

Tags: part-identification, technic

Red, LEGO Technic, cylinder shape and both sides slope inwards, at different gradients.
[image]

Answer (score 13):

That is [Vehicle, Tipper Drum 3 x 6 x 10 Half with 4 Pin Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57792). Red colored piece was used in just [single set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57792&colorID=5&in=A) - Neptune Carrier (8075):

[image]