# What is the length of this axle? like 5L

Tags: part-identification, technic

What is the axle length of the axle circled in red like 5L

[image]

Comment: Hi Carltrains and welcome to Bricks.SE! Are you per chance the author of [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/17527/3631), also named "carl"? If so, you can (and should) [merge the two accounts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to ease administration on everyone (including you). Wish you a happy and productive stay!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a [3L axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4519#T=C) to me.

[image]

It's the same length as [the blue pin next to it](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6558#T=C&C=7) which is also 3L. The 3L axle also typically comes in medium grey.

Comment: In recent sets about just as frequently in yellow, however this is not likely a recent set...